# How do I get Maven Site Descriptors to deploy to Artifactory?

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin, maven-site-plugin

I'm trying to generate a site for project that has a parent project and getting the following error.

```
[INFO] Parent project loaded from repository: com.mycompany:java-parent:pom:2.0.8
[INFO] Parent project loaded from repository: com.mycompany:parent:pom:2.0.8
Downloading: http://mycompany.com:8083/artifactory/ecommerce-repos/com/mycompany/parent/java-parent/2.0.8/java-parent-2.0.8-site_en.xml
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.mycompany:java-parent:xml:site_en:2.0.8' in repository eecomdev1-eecom (http://mycompany.com:8083/artifactory/ecommerce-repos)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/mycompany/parent/java-parent/2.0.8/java-parent-2.0.8-site_en.xml
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'com.mycompany:java-parent:xml:site_en:2.0.8' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Connection refused
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] SiteToolException: The site descriptor cannot be resolved from the repository: IOException: Unable to locate site descriptor: Permission denied
```

I'm unsurprised that it can't find it at repo1. A check of our company repository showed that the site_en file has not been deployed to our artifactory.

The site does generate from the machine where we do most of our builds. It turns out that because it built the actual releases for parent and java-parent it has the site_en.xml file in its local repository (the one on the local disk).

I figure to get going I need 1 of 2 possible solutions:

1. A way to tell the child project to stop trying to find the parent projects site.xml.
2. A way to deploy the site.xml files to artifactory.

My attempts at finding either solution have failed. The only way I can get the site xml files into the local artifactory is by running a full mvn release:prepare release:perform. I can't figure out how to make it deploy these files to artifactory or how to generate these files without actually doing a release.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

did you try instructions from http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/maven-3.html#Site_descriptor_attachment?
with this configuration in place, you should be able to simply `mvn deploy`

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is related to this open bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSITE-639

Comment: It is -- the solution for me was to avoid the mirrors configuration in my settings.xml file when running the site goal.